# Calculate approximate date from approximate timespan

Tags: c#, date, date-arithmetic

Since Sony changed how their trophy server authentication works, I am looking for an alternative solution to approximate trophy dates. The UK Playstation Network website has a string underneath unlocked trophies approximating how long ago trophies were earned. I have the following code:

```
private TimeSpan ParseTimeSpan(string datestring)
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
    datestring = datestring.Replace("Attained:", ""); // strip Attained:
    string[] parts = datestring.Split(' ');
    int numeric = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    string duration = parts[1];
    switch(duration)
    {
        case "minutes":
            ts = new TimeSpan(0, numeric, 0);
            break;
        case "hours":
            ts = new TimeSpan(numeric, 0, 0);
            break;
        case "days":
            ts = new TimeSpan(numeric, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case "months":
            ts = new TimeSpan(numeric * 30, 0, 0);
            break;
        case "years":
            ts = new TimeSpan(numeric * 365, 0, 0);
            break;
    }
    return ts;
}
```

If I have the string `Attained:17 months ago` underneath one of my trophies, it should take the current month and subtract 17 months. If I have the string `Attained:3 hours ago`, it should take the current date and subtract 3 hours to approximate an earned date. If I have the string `Attained: 5 minutes ago`, it should take the current date and subtract 5 minutes to approximate an earned date.

My plan is have this code run as a web service and accompany with a desktop client. I'm unsure of whether I should return a TimeSpan or do just calculate the date directly? Is there a better approach? Not all months are 30 days and some years are more than 365 days (leap years) so doing hard coded calculations won't necessarily work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about some months having 30 days and some not.  If you have the timespan you can directly decrement the current date by that span.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(5,0,0);
var earned = DateTime.Now - ts;
Console.Write(earned);
```

This can be done in or out of your service, but I would perform it in the service if the actual date is what's needed.

Also you can add a regular expression if you need to add some flexibility later on.

```
string input = "Attained:17 months ago";
string pattern = @"Attained:(?<value>[0-9]+) (?<unit>(years|months|days)) ago";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if(match.Success)
{
    int value = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value);
    string unit = match.Groups["unit"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    Console.WriteLine(unit);
}
```

Could make unit an enum as well

Answer (score 1):

[Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) is a much more flexible framework for working with time and date values than the types provided in the .NET base class library.  It includes, among other things, a `Period` type, which represents some amount of time in elapsed years, months, days, etc.  The actual elapsed time represented is *unfixed*.  As you say, some months or years are longer than others, so `Period` is the type to use if you are not dealing with a fixed amount of time (as opposed to a fixed `Duration`).  A `Period` can be added to the various date/time types in the Noda Time library.

While you can add and subtract a `TimeSpan` from a `DateTime[Offset]`, it's not a terribly useful type if you need to deal with units of time longer than hours.  Consider using Noda Time for nontrivial time/date computations.